# Left wing liberal snowflake

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

I've seen a comment that

**I am a left wing liberal snowflake.**

What does it mean?

I saw this on a Facebook comment; it's from Ellen talk show. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? You don't understand what the term **snowflake** means? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_(slang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Snowflake* is an insult that is used to describe someone perceived to be easily offended by things or generally very sensitive.

This term is frequently used in politics by those against *political correctness* (the avoidance of terms that could be deemed offensive in a social setting).

As you can imagine, someone who is a *snowflake* is very fragile, just like snowflakes that fall from the sky.